# React Is it okay to use URL to fill in information on page?

Tags: reactjs, url, react-redux

I 'm working on an app in which I'm using React and Redux. I was having trouble figuring out how to fill in the information on one of the pages in my app using Redux (which was my goal), so instead I found out how to do it using the URL. So my question is, is this okay? Will this end up causing bugs in my code down the road?

Here is an example of the page I was referring to:

```
const MovementPage = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const location = useLocation();
    const pathArray = location.pathname.split('/');
    const movementNameURL = (pathArray[2]);
    const notFound = () => {
        if (movementNameURL === undefined) {
            return (
                <div className={classes.notFound} >
                     Movement not found. Click Home button to return to Home Page.
                </div>
            )
        }

        return <PercentChart />
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <Header title={movementNameURL} />
            {notFound()}
        </div>
    );
};

 export default (MovementPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it can trouble you in the future when the app grows. So it will be better if you can use `react-router` for that URL stuff. Basically you can use this package to handle apps' navigation completely. It's really easy to configure. You can refer this documentation for that.

https://reactrouter.com/core/guides/quick-start